# Focus with WPF DataGrid and HeadersVisibility=None

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I encountered some strange behavior with the WPF DataGrid.

I create new rows in below example, by starting to type and go to the next row with pressing enter. For the row, where MaxHeight is reached, the first letter gets lost, due to some layout refresh.

C# ViewModel (left out the INotifyPropertyChanged boilerplate)

```
class Field<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _Value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); }
    }
}
class FormModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Field<string>> _FieldCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Field<string>> FieldCollection
    {
        get { return _FieldCollection; }
        set { _FieldCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldCollection"); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid
    MinHeight="50"
    MaxHeight="120"
    HeadersVisibility="None"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Value"
            Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I set `HeadersVisibility="Row"` instead of `None` on the DataGrid, then the whole sample works just fine. Did I miss anything or is it a bug on WPF side?

**Edit**

Here is a completed example, which I created from scratch to avoid any influence from other parts of the implementation.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <DataGrid
            MinHeight="40"
            MaxHeight="60"
            HeadersVisibility="None"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FieldCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Value"
                    Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

--

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    class Field<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
        {
            var tmp = PropertyChanged;
            if (tmp != null) tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        private T _Value;
        public T Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set { _Value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); }
        }
    }
    class FormModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
        {
            var tmp = PropertyChanged;
            if (tmp != null) tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Field<string>> _FieldCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Field<string>> FieldCollection
        {
            get { return _FieldCollection; }
            set { _FieldCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldCollection"); }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private FormModel f;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            f = new FormModel();
            f.FieldCollection = new ObservableCollection<Field<string>>(new[]
            {
                new Field<string>() { Value= "A"}
            });
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                grid1.DataContext = f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I changed Min/Max heights and initialization a bit. For me, the second row is created fine, the problem appears on the third row when I start typing there.

Comment: Sample works for me if DataGrid is placed inside Grid container. What container do you use?

Comment: See my edit for a full sample

Comment: sorry, works fine for me http://imgur.com/tGuDQ2F

Comment: Ok thanks for your time, guess I have to try it on a different machine later^^

Comment: Ok, confirmed it as a machine specific issue... strange one. Should I delete the question or what is the preferred way to deal with it?